# Active 1 day after signup using INTERVAL BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, casting, intervals

I am trying to count how many users were active after signup using BigQuery SQL and am getting this following error message:
`Invalid cast from STRUCT<STRING, INTERVAL> to TIMESTAMP`

```
SELECT
    r.gender, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.customerid)
FROM register_table r
JOIN activity_table a ON a.customerid = r.customerid
WHERE a.date = (r.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY 1
```

If I `CAST to timestamp` - I get the same error message. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I think you are missing call to `DATE_SUB` function. Something like `WHERE a.date = DATE_SUB(r.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Comment: `DATE_ADD(r.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)` i get this error: `No matching signature for function DATE_ADD for argument types: STRING, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signatures: DATE_ADD(DATE, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART); DATE_ADD(DATETIME, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART); DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this line:

```
WHERE a.date = (r.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

As was mentioned in another answer, you need some function there like DATE_ADD, DATE_SUB, etc. Otherwise, BigQuery won't know what to do with the INTERVAL 1 DAY clause.

But I think you've got another issue. That WHERE clause is going to pull records where the date in the activity table is exactly 1 day from the registration date. I think you want something more like this:

```
WHERE a.date BETWEEN r.date AND DATE_ADD(r.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Or, you might even get away with:

```
WHERE a.date <= DATE_ADD(r.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Data typing will be importance since this will assume that a.date and r.date are DATE or DATETIME columns. If not, then you'll need to do some casting or converting to correct them.

Comment: i get this error message: `No matching signature for function DATE_ADD for argument types: STRING, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signatures: DATE_ADD(DATE, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART); DATE_ADD(DATETIME, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART); DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART)`

Comment: @Dizz, what are the data types of your "date" columns? My guess is that they aren't DATE or DATETIME columns. That's almost certainly why you're receiving that error.